# Contact point between OverlapCircle and certain collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the contact point between a Collider and OverlapCircleAll to play an animation on that point.

This is the method I am using for the attack.

```
private IEnumerator BasicAttackBehaviour()
    {
        canAttack = false;
        Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos, attackRange, whatIsEnemy);
        for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
        {
            enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponentInParent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
        }
        PlayAttackAnimation();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackDelay);
        canAttack = true;
    }
```

And this is the "TakenDamage" method:

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        GameObject bloodEffect = Instantiate(takenDamageVFX, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
```

I want to instantiate the VFX "bloodEffect" on the position the enemy is hitten instead of "transform.position".

[image: This is how it looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to switch to CircleCastAll, it will give you contact points in world space coordinates:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCastAll.html

You can set the distance parameter to 0.0f if you don't want to do a moving circle and just a single non-moving circle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, this resolved my problem.
I will post the result just if someone more needs the example.
Thank you so much. You are the one.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question and thanking to the boss whom resolved my question above, here goes my fix just in case someone needs to visualise the example.

```
private IEnumerator BasicAttackBehaviour2()
    {
        canAttack = false;
        RaycastHit2D[] raycastHits = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(attackPos, attackRange, directionLookingAt, 0, whatIsEnemies);
        for(int i = 0; i < raycastHits.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector2 pointHitten = raycastHits[i].point;
            raycastHits[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage, pointHitten);
        }

        PlayAttackAnimation();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackDelay);
        canAttack = true;
    }
```

Using CircleCastAll I am able to retrieve the point of the RaycastHit2D and pass it to the enemy.

And then, I can display the blood effect on the right position of the impact.

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage, Vector2 pointHitten)
    {
        health -= damage;
        GameObject bloodEffect = Instantiate(takenDamageVFX, pointHitten, transform.rotation);
    }
```